# How to show signal if the Price crossover and crossunder the Hullma?

Tags: pine-script

How to show the Buy and Sell signal if

1. The price is crossing over the Hullma show "BUY" and Arrow up bolow the candle in RED
2. The price is crossing under the Hullma show "SELL" and Arrow down above the candle in GREEN

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do, can be done using the `plotshape()` function:

```
plotshape(series, 
          title, 
          style, 
          location, 
          color,
          offset, 
          text, 
          textcolor, 
          editable, 
          size, 
          show_last, 
          display
          )
```

you can get more info [here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_plotshape).

this is the code to your example:

```
//@version=5

// Hull Moving Average (Hullma)
hma = ta.hma(close, 25)

// Conditions
cond_1 = ta.crossover(close, hma)  //close crosses over hma
cond_2 = ta.crossunder(close, hma) //close crosses under hma

// Plot
plotshape(cond_1 ? low : na, color=color.red, style=shape.triangleup, text = "BUY", textcolor = color.red,location=location.belowbar)
plotshape(cond_2 ? high : na, color=color.green, style=shape.triangledown, text = "SELL", textcolor = color.green,location=location.abovebar)
```

It should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ngr26.png).

Comment: Thank you! Btw, how to add the hma to the  pine as well

Comment: What do you mean exactly? If you want it on the chart, you have to plot it by `plot(ta.hma(close, 25))` and settings the `overlay` to true in `indicator(NAME, overlay=true)`. The HMA itself is a feature of pine version 5 `ta.hma()`